# Excel VBA code to copy a row if an uppercase or a lowercase in a column to next sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a row to another sheet (sheet4) when in column Z a upper case X is present and when on another row a lower case x is present in the same column. Thus automatically copying both rows to sheet4.

To further explain

I need the VBA code to pick up both letters throughout the current sheet in just column Z

Thanks

Comment: "I need code" is not a question! Please read at least the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use this site!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this shoudl do it.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim Rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim rw As Long
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Z:Z")
rw = 1
For Each cell In Rng
If LCase(cell.Value) = "X" Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rw, "A") = cell.Offset(0, -1)
rw = rw + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

However, I don't know what this means:
"when on another row a lower case x is present in the same column."

What is the logic???